# How to ORDER MySQL results while excluding a string from the order title

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Im trying use MySQL to order by excluding "excl" if it's found at the start of a string, and using what ever comes after "excl" to order the results.

So it will order like this:

**title a name**
excl **title b name2**
**title c name**
**title d name**

But not:

**title a name**
**title c name**
**title d name**
excl **title b name2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to tell the `ORDER` clause that if the string begins with the text you're looking for, then use a substring that comes after that string.  So "excl title a" becomes "title a" as far as the `ORDER` process is concerned.

```
SELECT  title
FROM    table_name
ORDER BY
IF (SUBSTRING(LOWER(title), 1, 5) = 'excl ',
    SUBSTRING(title, 6),
    title
)
```

Comment: That makes sense, and better yet it works, thanks. I can think of some other cases where SUBSTRING may come in handy now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: misread the question, I thought rows starting with excl should go to the end, so the CASE needs to use substring() like in enobrev's answer.

```
...
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN title_column LIKE 'excl%' THEN substring(title, 6)
      ELSE title_column
   END
```

Comment: I like this.  Nice and clean.  I imagine both solutions are pretty slow on a large data set.